# Show ordered sentences in a VC with next and previous Buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to develop the next stuff:

[image: View]

I want to show an organized array of sentences when we click next or previous button. I mean "label" text is the beginning and if we click next Button the Simulator would show : "Sentence one", "Sentence two".... etc.

But if we click previous button it would start to decrease the sentences to the previous ones.

It doesn't work correctly, because I start clicking next and all seems perfect, but we click previous and it moves one sentence up, another click and it returns to the same sentence, then it starts to decrease.

The code :

```
class DescubreAQue: NSObject {


    var frase : String


    init( frase :String) {


        self.frase = frase
    }



class AQueVinimosAEsteMundo: UIViewController {


var frase = ""

    var data : [DescubreAQue] = []


    var pounter : Int = 0


    @IBOutlet weak var labelTexto: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        populate()

    }

    func populate() {

        data.append(DescubreAQue (frase: "1"))

        data.append(DescubreAQue (frase: "2"))

        data.append(DescubreAQue (frase: "3"))

        data.append(DescubreAQue (frase: "4"))

        data.append(DescubreAQue (frase: "5"))

    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        labelTexto.text = data[pounter].frase

        pounter++

        if (pounter == data.count) {

            pounter = 0

        }                                                
    }


    @IBAction func previousButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        labelTexto.text = data[pounter].frase

        pounter-- ;

        if ( pounter <= 0) {

            pounter = 0
        }

    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand your example.. What happens when you open the app, click 4 times next and then 5 times previous? And what should it be the correct output?

Comment: Here is a little clearer: 

We start clicking next button until sentence 4 .

Now we click previous and label move forward to number 5, then return to 4 , then 3 , 2 ,1.

Comment: The correct way would be when it shows us the sentences in the correct order clicking the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are setting the `labelTexto.text = data[pounter].frase` before incrementing/decrementing. I bet that if you increment after decrementing it will show first the previous and then it will start to increment. So what I'll do is change your outlets to these ones:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    pounter++
    if (pounter == data.count) {
        pounter = 0
    }                                                

    labelTexto.text = data[pounter].frase
}


@IBAction func previousButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    pounter-- ;
    if ( pounter <= 0) {
        pounter = 0
    }

    labelTexto.text = data[pounter].frase
}
```

Also you should start the `pounter` in -1.